# top_n for 2 conditions

Tags: r, top-n

I have a question regarding top_n function of dplyr. How can I use the top_n function two extract values based on two columns.

Following example: I have a data frame DT. Now I want to extract the top 5 rows. But I want to first order it based on Y. And then based on X. So at the end of the day I retrieve a data frame like RESULT.
Thank you for your help!

````
X<-c(2,8,7,6,4,4,3)
Y<-c(10,9,9,8,8,8,8)
DT<-data.frame(Term,X,Y)```

# What I tried so far
DT %>% top_n(n=5)
DT %>% top_n(n=5, w=X)
DT %>% top_n(n=5) %>% top_n(n=5, w=X)

# What I want to have
X<-c(2,8,7,6,4,4)
Y<-c(10,9,9,8,8,8)
Result<-data.frame(Term,X,Y)
````

Comment: You want to extract top 5 rows based on which column ? How do you get your `Result` dataframe ?

Comment: I have DT and want to get RESULT. I just posted RESULT, so it gets clear what I want to have.

Answer (score 2):

top_n can only be used for 1 variable.
You use arrange then head, for example:

```
df =data.frame(
Term = sample(letters,20,replace=T),
X=sample(1:5,20,replace=T),
Y=sample(1:5,20,replace=T)
)
# if you want the top 5 values
df %>% arrange(desc(X),desc(Y)) %>% head(5)
# if you want top 5 unique values, i.e ties count as 1
df %>% arrange(desc(X),desc(Y)) %>%
mutate(rank=cumsum(!duplicated(.))) %>% filter(rank<=5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the row in the 5th and 6th position have the same X and Y values and I want R to extract both since they are equal. Top_n does this but head not.

Comment: Ok I see. Then what you need is not well defined right. So you want the top 5 unique values? And according to the example, you can just do DT %>% arrange(desc(X),desc(Y))

Comment: Ok I have edited the code, but I am sure top_n does not do what you claimed

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. This helped. But there is one small problem. My first colum is a character vector. This dissapears when I use your syntax. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data? And explain what do you want to sort by?

Comment: You can see my example above, the "Term" column doesn't disappear